# NAT forward and keep client IP

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, port-forwarding, nat

I have a server in the middle of my VPN connection as explained:

`` Client: `123.123.123.123` --> Linux 1: `1.2.3.4` --> Linux 2: `5.6.7.8` ``

So, `5.6.7.8` is the VPN server and `1.2.3.4` is only a middle-man for clients to access `5.6.7.8` (because clients can't directly access `5.6.7.8`).

I already tried NAT forward in `1.2.3.4` and I can connect to the VPN server, but on `5.6.7.8` all the incoming traffic is from `1.2.3.4` and not from `123.123.123.123` which is the client's real IP address.

iptables commands I used:

```
#skip port 22
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4

#forward everything to VPN server
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

What I want to achieve is to see the client's real IP (`123.123.123.123`) on `5.6.7.8` which is the VPN server.

Comment: In most VPN connections (certainly most the regular users would have) a VPN connection cannot have a break in the middle . You probably need to configure from end point to end point and skirt around any break.

Comment: @John I configured v2ray on the destination server.

Comment: Assuming something in the path does reverse path filtering or NAT - which is almost a given - you cant do this with just IPTables.  You need to set up a VPN between 123.123.123.123 and 5.6.7.8.